# PHP - SOAP/WSDL method doesn't show all the parameters

Tags: php, wsdl

I'm having some problem with WSDL. When I try to retrieve the data using Soap Client, the function doesn't show all the parameters defined by service. The interesting part is that, if I'll try to access the service script directly - it will display the correct array, with enough parameters.

What might be the problem? As for cashing, I've tried the following, but without any luck:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client = new SoapClient("crm.wsdl", array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE)) or die('error');
```

Comment: show WSDL file with parts where are declared parameters method. part: `<types>`.
have you any error/exception?

Comment: Thanks Piotr for you comment. There is no error or exception, furthermore, I've copied the wsdl file and service file and it worked like a charm :)))